# File upload in Spring MVC gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, file, jsp

I have a simple JSP form as follows:

```
<p>Please select a file and <i>click</i> <i>Upload file</i> to upload the file to the server:</p>
    <c:url value="/upload/display" var="displayUploadedFileURL" />                   
    <form:form action="${displayUploadedFileURL}" method="post" modelAttribute="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">            
        <input type="file" name="file" />                       
        <input type="submit" value="Upload file" />&nbsp;<form:errors path="file" />
        <input type="Reset" value="Reset">           
    </form:form>
```

Which is for a user to upload a file to the server. The controller's method is as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/upload")
public class UploadController {

@Autowired
private UploadValidator uploadValidator; 



    @RequestMapping(value="/display", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String displayUploadedFile(@ModelAttribute("upload") Upload upload,
                                      BindingResult bindingResult,
                                      Model model) {                

        // Validate Upload.
        uploadValidator.validate(upload, bindingResult);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {  
            return ("view/upload/select");  
        }
        else {
            String fileName = upload.getFile().getOriginalFilename();
            System.out.println("Here: " + upload.getFile().getOriginalFilename());            
            model.addAttribute("fileName", fileName);
            return ("view/upload/display");
       }       
   }
```

...

But when I select a file and use the *Upload file* button I get the following:

```
Your page request has caused a NullPointerException: error:

library.validator.UploadValidator.validate(UploadValidator.java:29)
library.controller.upload.UploadController.displayUploadedFile(UploadController.java:45)
```

The validator concerned is very simple:

```
package library.validator;

import library.model.Upload;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

@Component
public class UploadValidator implements Validator {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UploadValidator.class);   

public UploadValidator() {
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class cls) {
    return Upload.class.isAssignableFrom(cls);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    logger.info(UploadValidator.class.getName() + ".validate() method called.");  

    Upload upload = (Upload) target;
    if (upload.getFile().getSize() == 0) {
        errors.rejectValue("file", "file.required");
    }       
}
```

}

I have all the relevant `.jar` files in the application's `.lib` folder, and I'mincluding the following:

```
<bean id="uploadValidator" class="library.validator.UploadValidator" />        

<!-- Spring multipartResolver. -->         
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

In the `DispatcherServlet`.

The `Upload` object type is as follows:

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class Upload {

    private MultipartFile file;
```

And appropriate getter and setter.

So why is my code not working?

Stacktrace for current problem, i.e. allowing for changes to controller method in answer below, is:

> org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.resolveName(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:171)
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:89)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:79)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:394)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy to see a working solution.

Comment: Hang on a second do not apply changes, I figure you are using spring form.

Comment: Need to see content of UploadValidator class. Your code should work fine problem might be in UploadValidator class.

Comment: I have added the full validator code.

Comment: Apparently `getFile()` is null.

Comment: Yes, but why? I can't work that out.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring the `multipartResolver` bean is important thing, but also you should check that your .xml config file with this bean is imported in your general `applicationContext.xml`, if you have some. I had same problem and this did the thing.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been solved. The problem was that the following was incorrectly defined in the `DispatcherServlet`:

```
<!-- Spring multipartResolver. -->         
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```